# How do I access objects in a linked-list in C++

Tags: c++, object, linked-list

I'm very use to working with arrays and vectors, but now I'm playing with some STD::lists, as well as a custom list class I made.

Let's say I have a simple class, Stock.

```
//stock.h
class Stock{
public:
    Stock(); //default constructor
    Stock(string, double); //overloaded constructor
    void setSymbol(string); //sets stock symbol
    void setPrice(double);
    string getSymbol();
    double getPrice();        
private:
    string symbol;
    double price;
};
```

Now in a separate file I have my int main to test.

```
#include "stock.h"
#include <list>

int main(){
    list<Stock> portfolio;

    Stock Google("GOOG", 500);
    Stock Apple("APPL", 300);
    Stock Chipotle("CMG", 200);

    portfolio.push_back(Google);
    portfolio.push_back(Apple);
    portfolio.push_back(Chipotle);
}
```

Now if this was a vector or array, I would have no problem, I'm just completely loss on the linked-list equivalent of the following:

```
for(int i=0; i <portfolio.size(); i++){
    portfolio[i].getSymbol();
    portfolio[i].getPrice();
 }
```

Or something along those lines...I have no lecture/training in Linked-Lists so I'm really trying to do my best in teaching myself--but I'm stuck on basic manipulation. I'm using STL::list right now, but really trying to make my own class as well.

Comment: You should really be using your list class's `iterator`. Unfortunately I'm too lazy to tell you how right now, but look it up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for(int i= portfolio.begin(); i <portfolio.size(); i++)
```

If this worked for a std::vector, it was *only* by sheer accident. I have no idea how that might have worked for a vector.

`std::any_stl_container::begin()` returns an object called an "iterator". Specifically, an object of type `std::any_stl_container::iterator`. An iterator is kind of like a generalized pointer: it refers to an element in an STL container.

The iterator returned by `begin` is the iterator that references the first element in the list. You can move iterators around like pointers. For example:

```
std::list<Stock> portfolio;
...
std::list<Stock>::iterator currElem = portfolio.begin();
++currElem; //Now points to the second element in the list.
Stock &secondStock = *currElem;
```

In order to iterate over all of the elements in a list, you need two iterators: the first one, and the iterator for the element *after* the last element in the list. Fortunately, this is returned by the `std::any_stl_container::end()` function. So, your loop should look like:

```
typedef std::list<Stock>::iterator StockIt;
for(StockIt i = portfolio.begin(); i != portfolio.end(); ++i) /* Prefer pre-increment with iterators */
{
    i->getSymbol();
    i->getPrice();
}
```

This will work for *any* of the usual STL containers.

Comment: The original code of course wouldn't compile... I corrected that typo (s/he was clearly using 0 as start instead of `portfolio.begin()`) and also `pushback` into `push_back`.

Comment: @Nicol-Bolas Thanks. It seems like I'm having a tough time thinking in pointers/iterators instead of accessing an element directly. I just threw together my std::vector off the top of my head, it's likely that code was not working.

Answer (score 2):

You have iterators as `begin()` and `end()` for [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/) also:

```
for (list<stock>::iterator it = portfolio.begin() ; it != portfolio.end(); it++)
{
  // use 'it' to access the current element (i.e. *it)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/). Every STL container has them, even vector. They behave similarly to pointers; they can be dereferenced with * or ->, they can be incremented, they can be compared.

```
for( list<Stock>::iterator it = portfolio.begin(); it != portfolio.end(); it++ ){
    it->getSymbol();
    it->getPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object of type `std::list` is very inefficient if you try to compute its length, because such an operation would have linear time.

Therefore with lists, you cannot compare iterators with the `<`  and `>` operators. It is also ill-advised to try to get the nth element with the operator `[]`.

Also, you should not mix `begin()` and `size()` which are respectively an iterator and an integer.

The proper way to iterate over an `std::list` is to use the pair of iterators `begin()` and `end()` and to increment your iterator until it reaches the `end()`.

So, two ways:

```
for(std::list<stock>::const_iterator i = my_list.cbegin(); i != my_list.cend(); ++i)
{
    // access a “const stock &” object via *i
}
```

or

```
for(std.:list<stock>::iterator i = my_list.begin(); i != my_list.end(); ++i)
{
    // access a “stock &” object via *i
}
```